# Using Py_buffer and PyMemoryView_FromBuffer with different itemsizes

Tags: python, cpython, pybuffer, pep3118

This question is related to a previous question I asked. Namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033683/calling-a-python-function-from-a-c-thread-with-a-mutable-c-array) if anyone is interested. Basically, what I want to do is to expose a C array to Python using a `Py_buffer` wrapped in a `memoryview`-object. I've gotten it to work using `PyBuffer_FillInfo` (work = I can manipulate the data in Python and write it to stdout in C), but if I try to roll my own buffer I get a segfault *after* the C function returns.

I need to create my own buffer because PyBuffer_FillInfo assumes that the format is char, making the itemsize field 1. I need to be able to provide items of size 1, 2, 4 and 8.

Some code, this is a working example:

```
Py_buffer *buf = (Py_buffer *) malloc(sizeof(*buf));
int r = PyBuffer_FillInfo(buf, NULL, malloc(sizeof(char) * 4), 4, 0, PyBUF_CONTIG);
PyObject *mv = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(buf);
//Pack the memoryview object into an argument list and call the Python function
for (blah)
  printf("%c\n", *buf->buf++); //this prints the values i set in the Python function
```

Looking at the implementation of `PyBuffer_FillInfo`, which is really simple, I rolled my own function to be able to provide custom itemsizes:

```
//buffer creation function
Py_buffer *getReadWriteBuffer(int nitems, int itemsize, char *fmt) {
  Py_buffer *buf = (Py_buffer *) malloc(sizeof(*buf));
  buf->obj = NULL
  buf->buf = malloc(nitems * itemsize);
  buf->len = nitems * itemsize;
  buf->readonly = 0;
  buf->itemsize = itemsize;
  buf->format = fmt;
  buf->ndim = 1;
  buf->shape = NULL;
  buf->strides = NULL;
  buf->suboffsets = NULL;
  buf->internal = NULL;
  return buf;
}
```

How i use it:

```
Py_buffer *buf = getReadWriteBuffer(32, 2, "h");
PyObject *mv = PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(buf);
// pack the memoryview into an argument list and call the Python function as before

for (blah)
  printf("%d\n", *buf->buf); //this prints all zeroes even though i modify the array in Python

return 0;
//the segfault happens somewhere after here
```

The result of using my own buffer object is a segfault after the C function returns. I really don't understand why this happens at all. Any help would be most appreciated.

**EDIT**
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297026/assignment-into-python-3-x-buffers-with-itemsize-1?rq=1), which I failed to find before, itemsize > 1 might not even be supported at all. Which makes this question even more interesting. Maybe I could use `PyBuffer_FillInfo` with a large enough block of memory to hold what I want (32 C floats for example). In that case, the question is more about how to assign Python floats to the `memoryview` object in the Python function. Questions questions.

Comment: There is a memory leak if `Py_buffer` malloc'ed. Use stack allocated `Py_buffer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in lack of answers I decided to take another approach than the one I originally intended. Leaving this here in case someone else hits the same snag.

Basically, instead of creating a buffer (or bytearray, equiv.) in C and passing it to Python for the extension user to modify. I simply redesigned the code slightly, so that the user returns a bytearray (or any type that supports the buffer interface) from the Python callback function. This way I need not even worry about the size of the items since, in my case, all the C code does with the returned object is to extract its buffer and copy it to another buffer with a simple `memcpy`.

Code:

```
PYGILSTATE_ACQUIRE; //a macro i made
PyObject *result = PyEval_CallObject(python_callback, NULL);
if (!PyObject_CheckBuffer(result))
  ; //raise exception

Py_buffer *view = (Py_buffer *) malloc(sizeof(*view));
int error = PyObject_GetBuffer(result, view, PyBUF_SIMPLE);
if (error)
  ; //raise exception

memcpy(my_other_buffer, view->buf, view->len);

PyBuffer_Release(view);
Py_DECREF(result);
PYGILSTATE_RELEASE; //another macro
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think you would leak the buffer in above code, unless there was a free() call for it somewhere later -- i.e. loking at PyBuffer_Release() calls in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytearrayobject.c , the memory management (i.e. freeing the struct) still needs to be done